# Web not showing data loaded from html file in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am loading content in webview from local html file residing in  resources folder

```
 NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"]; 


 NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  error:nil];
 [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath]]];
```

Comment: NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  error:nil];
 [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  try this

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to load html file which is in resource folder

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
 [webView loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                                                              [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```